# How do you change the color of unselected items in a Tab Bar?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar

I'm trying to change the color of the unselected item images in my Tab Bar from the default gray color to the actual color of the image (white), but my efforts have been unsuccessful. There are several threads related to this question on Stack Overflow, but many of them seem to be outdated.

[Tab Bar with Home and Profile icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGvLi.png)

As you can see from the picture, the unselected Profile icon on the right has a default gray color. After doing some research, I've tried running the solution below in the App Delegate file to change its color to white, but sadly this hasn't worked. I'm a novice Swift programmer (incidentally, this is also my first post), so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    tabBarController.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .white

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the icon images Black, if they are white Im not sure it will work. As in the actual image themselves should be black in the assets folder not white.

If you add a tabbar from the story board you can put these line of code in that method in the appDelegate method shown in your post

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = .white
```

Comment: Thanks, Shane. This didn't work unfortunately. But I'm starting to think that this might be an issue related to the simulator. The unselected icons appear in white on the Storyboard, but for some reason, they turn gray on the simulator.

Comment: For those interested, the context for what might have gone wrong before: When I typed in 'UITabBar.appearance()' in Xcode and then starting typing '.unselectedItemTintColor' Xcode was not auto-suggesting this property, which made me believe I was doing something wrong. Based on Apple's documentation, it looks like they deprecated the property 'selectedImageTintColor' and then added this new '.unselectedItemTintColor' property that Xcode hasn't quite registered yet. Long story short, I've run into similar problems with Xcode misbehaving and creating all sorts of confusion as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use UITabBar.appearence(). unselectedItemTintColor, more information here
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/legacy_customizations

Comment: Xcode won't allow me to access the unselectedItemTintColor property that way. The only way I've been able to access it is by initializing UITabBarController, as indicated in my post. And that method did not work.

Answer (score 0):

set isTranslucent to false by adding line in your tabbarviewcontroller  tabBar.isTranslucent = false

it worked for me